# How to stop setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="ccc">10</span> <span id="start">start</span> <span id="stop">stop</span>

$('#start').click(function(){
    var c = $('#ccc').text();
         var inter =   setInterval(function() {
                    c--;
                    $('#ccc').text(c);
            }, 1000);
}); 

$('#stop').click(function(){
     clearInterval(inter);
    });
```

how i must rewrite this for correctly use STOP?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/c3hZh/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inter` needs to be in-scope for both functions. Wrap both functions with a closure so that you can avoid polluting the global namespace with a new variable.

```
(function ($) {
  var inter;

  $('#start').click(function(){
    var c;
    c = parseInt($('#ccc').text()); //make sure you're getting a numeric value
    //don't forget to clear any existing interval before setting a new one:
    if (inter) {
      clearInterval(inter);
    }
    inter = setInterval(function() {
      c--;
      $('#ccc').text(c);
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#stop').click(function() {
    clearInterval(inter);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 3):

`inter` is a local variable.
It doesn't exist outside your callback.

You need to use a global variable.

Comment: Hopefully not global, but it certainly needs to be accessible to both callbacks.

Comment: He doesn't "*need*" to use a global variable, he might as well call `$('#stop').click (...)` in the same scope as he's doing `setInterval`.

Comment: @refp: That would add a separate click handler per click of the other button.  `.one` would be much better there.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, my wording was to make it easier to understand what I meant, he should use `jQuery.one` if he decides to go with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
var inter = 0;
$('#start').click(function(){
    var c = $('#ccc').text();
         inter =   setInterval(function() {
                    c--;
                    $('#ccc').text(c);
            }, 1000);
}); 

$('#stop').click(function(){
     clearInterval(inter);
    });
```