# Notify promise angular remove callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q, angular-promise

I would like to notify multiple controllers of external changes from a service.
I know that i can do this by using a deferred object and calling notify on it and registering a callback on that.

e.g

```
// in service
        $timeout(function() {
                defered.notify('In progress')}
            , 0)

//in controller
    var promise = myService.promise
    promise.then(function(success) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("error");
    }, function(update) {
        console.log("got an update!");
    }) ;
```

Is there a way to remove my notify callback when the controller is destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$on, $broadcast and $emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to achieve a similar behavior.

Just `$broadcast(name, args);` an event and register a listener `$on(name, listener);`.

So when you got your data you just broadcast to everybody that you've got it.

```
$broadcast('gotTheData', actualDataObject);
```

Then in your controllers

```
 $on('gotTheData', function(event, actualDataObject)
     {
         ... update controller data ...
      });
```

Note that in the example I've added only one `actualDataObject`, but you can pass multiple arguments from the `$broadcast` to `$on`. For more details refer to the documentation (see link above).

As per the comments to @Scott's answer you highlighted one important aspect: you need to unregister the `$on` when you destroy the controller through the "Returns a deregistration function for this listener." (see the docs) at `$on` returns. There is a question that targets specifically this issue: [How can I unregister a broadcast event to rootscope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856341/how-can-i-unregister-a-broadcast-event-to-rootscope-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT DUE TO FURTHER QUESTION DETAILS**

You could cancel the $timeout when you destroy the controller:

Create the `$timeout` as so...

```
$scope.myTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                defered.notify('In progress')}
            , 0);
```

In the controller add this:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.myTimeout);
});
```

In my experience this appears to clean everything up.

To clear just the notify callback itself, use the suggested `$broadcast, $emit`(see @Pio's answer) A guide to the difference between them is [here](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/).

**Its important to know the difference!**

Comment: I just want to delete the individual notify callback from the controller as there could be many of them

Comment: Well in that case, I'd be tempted to use events ($broadcast, $emit etc) but be careful as you must understand the difference when using them!

Comment: Do you need to unregister to $on in the controller when it is destroyed?

Comment: The guide I linked it should explain, I don't think you need too as I think its automatic, but others might know better!

Comment: @user1168234 - had a quick look, if the scope is in a controller then angular will unregister it for you. Otherwise you can unregister your even by calling the returned function. (i.e. var myevent = $scope.$on('someEvents', handleSomeEvent);
myevent(); // unregister the event)