# AngularJS $routeChangeStart only first time event

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to only listen for the VERY first route start and none of the others?  Obvs this could be done with a variable but was wondering if there was an event for this instead.

```
       $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            Auth.authorize().then(function(){
                // only want to happen the first time
                // $location.path('dlp');
            },function(){
                $location.path('login');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unsubscribe from $rootScope.$on broadcasts if you assign it to a variable and call it as a function:

```
var offCallMeFn = $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current){
        Auth.authorize().then(function(){
            // only want to happen the first time
            // $location.path('dlp');
        },function(){
            $location.path('login');
        });
});

 //this will deregister that listener
offCallMeFn();
```

For handling authorization this seems like a bad idea however as users might access routes manually (e.g. from browser history) or possibly logout.

Source: [How to unsubscribe to a broadcast event in angularJS. How to remove function registered via $on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg)