# AngularJS directive $document click event is firing for all instances everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to attach an event to the document. when document is clicked I want to remove my directive element. but it is firing for all past instances also.

Below is the code:

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      $document.on('click',function(){
          iElement.slideUp('fast',function(){
              $(this).remove();
          });
      });
    }
```

Comment: you will have to remove the handler in the $destroy handler

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add jQuery events like this, the event will stay alive even after the directive is destroyed. You have to specifically turn the event off like this:

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  $document.on('click',function(){
      iElement.slideUp('fast',function(){
          $(this).remove();
          $document.off('click');
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to remove the handler in the destroy handelr

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    function handler() {
        iElement.slideUp('fast', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    $document.on('click', handler);
    scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $document.off('click', handler);
    })
}
```

Comment: "scope" doesn't have method "on". I get an error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @EugeneKuzmin sorry `scope.$on()`