# How to un-subscribe to a broadcast event in application module run block

Tags: angularjs

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg) post whilst reading up on the correct ways for cleaning up event listeners attached to $scope in angularjs.

I am listening to an event on $rootScope in my app module run block:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
    //do stuff here...
  });
}]);
```

Since $scope is not available in the run block, can I listen for the destroy event on $rootScope instead?

So:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  var listenerFn = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
    //do stuff here...
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$destroy', listenerFn);
}]);
```

I'm not so sure I can do it this way looking around various posts and docs online since it doesn't look like $rootScope has a destroy event. So what's the correct approach here?

Comment: _"Since $scope is not available in the run block"_ - It is, but it's called `$rootScope` ^^ _"it doesn't look like $rootScope has a destroy event"_ the root scope gets destroyed when you close or leave the page. Everything will be gone then, so there's nothing to clean up.

Comment: Yes ok, I did wonder if I needed to worry about it. The thing is, I'm actually using ESLint with this plugin enabled - https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular. It's throwing up a warning based on this rule - https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/docs/on-watch.md - Looks like I wont be able to get around this then.

Comment: Since there's nothing to clean up you may as well disable the eslint rule on that line with `// eslint-disable-line angular/on-watch`