# Angular UI Router - chnage state based on Keydown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wish to change states based on keypresses - i.e. M key loads menu, G key loads Guide - they are completely separate views.

I am working on the assumption, in a global directive that I can do

```
$document.on 'keydown', ( event ) ->
    if event.keyCode == 77
        $state.go 'mainMenu'
```

However when the view is destoryed it is still answering to these key presses, I want to effectively stop that

In the directive handling the view

I have

```
scope.$on '$destroy', ->
    $document.off( 'keydown' )
```

However this would then stop all keys being published by the global directive

Any help appreciated on basically handling key navigation throughout a multi-state app

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$on` actually returns the event-listener destroyer function (or `$off` if you will) so i believe

```
var unsubscribeKeyDown = $document.on 'keydown', ( event ) ->
    if event.keyCode == 77
        $state.go 'mainMenu'
```

And

```
scope.$on '$destroy', ->
    unsubscribeKeyDown();
```

Should do it.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898795/4341456).

Comment: Keep getting un found function - tried the fat arrow in coffee but will not pick it up.