# How to stop broadcast event in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

How to stop broadcast event in angularjs? I have three controllers nested. When I broadcast an event from `ctrl1` controller, `ctrl2` and `ctrl3` controllers listen to this event. I want to stop `ctrl3` controller from listener event. How to do this?

```
<div  ng-controller="ctrl1" ng-click="ad2()">
        <div  ng-controller="ctrl2">
            <div  ng-controller="ctrl3">
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  

    studentReport.controller("ctrl1",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.ad2 = function(){
        $scope.$broadcast("text","hi");
    }
}])

studentReport.controller("ctrl2",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.$on("text",function(event,message){
        alert(message)
    });
}])

studentReport.controller("ctrl3",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.$on("text",function(event,message){
        alert(message)
    });
}])
```

Comment: Simply unregister to listen that event.

Comment: how to unregister the event @Ashish Kumawat

Comment: // subscribes...
  var myListener = $scope.$on('child', function (event, data) {
    // do something
  });

  // unsubscribes...
  // this would probably sit in a callback or something
  myListener();

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.on` returns a function you can use to deregister the event. So you can do something like this:

```
var deregisterKey = $scope.on('key', fn);

// stop listening
deregisterKey()
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14898795/3891533

Answer (score 1):

```
// subscribes...
  var myListener = $scope.$on('child', function (event, data) {
    // do something
  });

  // unsubscribes...
  // this would probably sit in a callback or something
  myListener();
```

> To unsubscribe listening event.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `alert(message)` try setting this...

```
 event.defaultPrevented = true;
```

Broadcast does not have the stopPropagation method thats why you have to use `defaultPrevented`