# AngularJS : Removing rootScope listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following code in a controller :

```
var deregisterSetPermissions =  $rootScope.$on("setPermissions", function () {
    [... some code used when the user click on a "create account" button...]
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterSetPermissions;
    [... and other listeners are unregistered ...]
}
```

When I leave the page, all the listeners are unregistered : I can see through the chrome developer console that $rootScope.$$listeners.setPermissions[] contains a single value, which is null.

When I come back to the page and after it loaded, $rootScope.$$listeners.setPermissions[0] contains null and $rootScope.$$listeners.setPermissions[1] contains the function the listener will have to call.
$rootScope.$$listenerCount.setPermissions is 1.

But when I click on the "create account" button, the function used by the "setPermissions" listener is called **twice** !
How can it be ?

**Here's what I tried :**
1- Checked that there are no other listeners created with the name "setPermissions"
2- Delete the content of the listener when the scope is destroyed :

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $rootScope.$$listeners.setPermissions=[];
    $rootScope.$$listenerCount.setPermissions = 0;
});
```

But still after that, if I leave the page and come back 3 times, a click on the "create account" button will cause the "setPermissions"-listener-function to be called 3 times...

It would be nice to understand **why** the listener's function is called more than once; and if you have a solution or an idea to help me going on, I am looking forward to reading it !

Comment: You're calling `deregisterSetPermissions()` with the trailing parens, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root of the problem.
There was an other rootScope-listener in a service which wasn't destroyed, which is emitting the "setPermissions" message. Thus, I could try all I wanted, but I was looking at the wrong place..

Answer (score 1):

`deregisterSetPermissions` is a function. To unsubscribe the listener, you have to call it.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    deregisterSetPermissions();
}
```

Generally, any time you find yourself using a function object that begins with the double dollar signs (`$$`) in Angular, it means you're doing something wrong - that's Angular's naming convention for something that isn't part of their public API!

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful information from this question:
[how to unsubscribe to a broadcast event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377796/3508277)

Which I used to construct an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('AppController', function($rootScope) {
  var appCtrl = this;

  $rootScope.manageNumbers = false;

  appCtrl.addNumber = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('addNumber');
  };
})

.controller('NumbersController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  var numCtrl = this;

  numCtrl.numbers = [];
  numCtrl.number = 0;

  // Register and set handle
  console.log('Register listener');
  var registerListener = $rootScope.$on('addNumber', addNumber);
  logListenerData();

  // Unregister
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    console.log('Unregister listener');
    registerListener();
    // $rootScope.$$listeners.addNumber.length = 0;
    logListenerData();
  });

  function addNumber() {
    numCtrl.numbers.push(numCtrl.number);
    numCtrl.number++;
  }

  function logListenerData() {
    console.log('$rootScope.$$listeners');
    console.log($rootScope.$$listeners);
    console.log('$rootScope.$$listenerCount');
    console.log($rootScope.$$listenerCount);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl">
    <button ng-click="$root.manageNumbers=true;" ng-if="!$root.manageNumbers">
      Start Number Management
    </button>
    <button ng-click="$root.manageNumbers=false;" ng-if="$root.manageNumbers">
      Stop Number Management
    </button>
    <button ng-click="appCtrl.addNumber()">
      Add Number
    </button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="NumbersController as numCtrl" ng-if="$root.manageNumbers">
    <p>
      <b>Numbers:</b>
      <span ng-repeat="number in numCtrl.numbers">
        {{ $last ? number : number + ', ' }}
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice a few things. Even when you unregister an event, unless that event was triggered while it was registered, it will have a "ghost" null value in the $$listeners but will not show up in the $$listenerCounts. With the commented out line that sets the length to 0 I was able to remove these ghosts, however; it causes no actual difference as far as I can tell.