# Check if a listener is already set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I add a listener in a service as follows:

```
app.service('hostService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {    
    this.addListener = function () {
        console.log("addListener")
        $rootScope.$on("messageFromSiteToHost", function (event, data) {
            action(data);
        })
    }
```

Then I realize that it happens that `hostService.addListener` is called several times by users, as a consequence, when there is a message of  `messageFromSiteToHost`, `action(data)` is called several times.

Does anyone know if there is a way to check if `$rootScope.$on("messageFromSiteToHost"` is already set (without using an auxiliary variable in the service). If it is already set, I don't want to add the listener twice.

Comment: why not remove the listener just before adding the new one.

Comment: So you need a variable to point to the function, right?

Comment: I am not familiar with angular, but check out this link, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898296/how-to-unsubscribe-to-a-broadcast-event-in-angularjs-how-to-remove-function-reg

Comment: @ThomasValadez Yes, in those answers, we need a variable like `var off = $rootScope.$on('$rootScope.$on("messageFromSiteToHost", function (event, data)'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything available in the framework to check for existing event listeners.

Can you explain the reason for your requirement not to use "an auxiliary variable in the service"?

What is the reason why you can't add a guard around the function?:

```
app.service('hostService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {    

    var listenerAdded = false;
    this.addListener = function () {
        if (listenerAdded){
            return;
        }
        listenerAdded = true;

        console.log("addListener")
        $rootScope.$on("messageFromSiteToHost", function (event, data) {
            action(data);
        })
    }

}]);
```

---

Also, if you find you need to do this a lot throughout your application then you can generalise the implementation or use something like [`lodash.once`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#once) to remove the boilerplate:

```
app.service('hostService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {    

    this.addListener = _.once(function () {
        console.log("addListener")
        $rootScope.$on("messageFromSiteToHost", function (event, data) {
            action(data);
        })
    });

}]);
```

Comment: There is no specific reason why I don't want to use "an auxiliary variable in the service", I just want to make sure if there is anything available in the framework...