# Angularjs - How to open custom modal on leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in a bit of a pickle.
I have a form in the page. When user makes it dirty and tries to leave the page, a custom modal (mostly bootstrap modal) should pop up with a confirmation message as in "are you sure you want leave?"

I made a plunker which uses native browser's alert box (and also bootstrap pop modal). Alert box works - commented out. But modal is not working.

http://embed.plnkr.co/6LHacFZhZ74TxmyFY8f8/preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thats not how onbeforeonunload works. If you don't return anything from the function that you assign to it, nothing happens

Comment: it may be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809686/showing-alert-in-angularjs-when-user-leaves-a-page

Comment: it looks $locationChangeStart do that

Comment: Does $locationChangeStart work on page reload too? Requirement is to get it work for all the cases: back button, url change, page reload, etc.

Comment: @jw56578, thats the thing. Since onbeforeunload needs a return, the popup modal wont successfully work.