# How to store data on closing of tab and browser in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to store closingtime after closing of tab and browser.that closing time should be stored in localstorage in angularjs.

I am using $localStorage and $window directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use... `beforeunload`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        return "Do you really want to close?"; 
    });
});
```

With pure JS

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Fbeforeunload

Comment: yes your code  is alerting me for leav browser or stay on browser in working on closing of tab or browser but

Comment: your code is alerting me for closing or staying into browser but how can i store closing time on close  of browser|| tab .Please suggest?

Comment: you can use $locationChangeStart or $stateChangeSuccess with the beforeunload event... look at this directive... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22866537/337128

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) events to handle this but with the condition that they will fire even while navigating to other sites on clicking links

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppController', function ($localStorage, $window) {
     $window.onunload = function () {
       $localStorage.setItem('LastLoggedOutTime', new Date());
     }
  });
```

Comment: above code will give onload time but i want closing time when i close tab or browser.Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('exitController', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.onExit = function() {
            // your function
        };

        $window.onbeforeunload =  $scope.onExit;
});
```